# Prevent upsert from failing

Tags: apex, dml

I have a list of Opportunities which I am trying to upsert. Say the list contains 6 Opportunities. Upsert operation of 3rd Opportunity fails. Will the first two Opportunities commit? What happens to rest of the Opportunities in the list? Is it possible to skip the Opportunity and upsert rest of the Opportunities without aborting the transaction?

Comment: depends on how you use the upsert statement, are you using upsert List_of_accounts/         Database.UpsertResult sr = Database.upsert(record,false); see here : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm

Comment: I was using upsert List_of_Records; Will try using the above example. Thanks!!

Comment: use Database.UpsertResult[] sr = Database.upsert(list_of_records,false);look at the link and it would give you an idea on partial processing of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rao's solution worked for me. I ended up using

```
   Database.UpsertResult[] sr = Database.upsert(list_of_records,false);
```